# it only enters the browser.get()

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I run the code I wrote, it only enters the
`browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/')` to the web I specified here. Nothing has changed and

```
username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined. Did you mean: 'webdriver'?
```

What could be the reason?
Code I wrote:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/')
sleep(2)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username_input.send_keys(username)
username_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

email_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

driver.quit()
username = '...'
email = '...'
reset_instagram_password(username, email)
```

Comment: As the error message says, the name `driver` isn't bound to anything.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the webdriver in variable `"browser = webdriver.Firefox()"`
But while searching for element you are using `"username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('username')"`

Change it to following...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/password/reset/')
sleep(2)

username_input = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
username_input.send_keys(username)
username_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

email_input = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
email_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(2)

driver.quit()
username = '...'
email = '...'
reset_instagram_password(username, email)
```